# Template error: every value of the context object of every Fn::Sub object must be a string or a function that returns a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want aws:SourceVpc to be added as list of string ["vpc-7830jkd", "vpc-a1236"] when i run this template in uat env and as string "vpc-1234"
when i run in perf. It is working fine in perf env but when i run in uat i got below error.

Template error: every value of the context object of every Fn::Sub object must be a string or a function that returns a string. Any suggestions ?

Can this achieved by combining select, join and findinmap.

```
 Mappings:
  mVpcId:
   menv:
    perf: "vpc-1234"
    uat: "vpc-7830jkd,vpc-a1236"
 
 islowenv: !Equals [ !Ref Env, "perf" ]
 
 Parameters:
   Env:
    Type: String
 
 Resources:
 apigateway:
   Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
     Properties:
    Name: mygateway
   EndpointConfiguration:
     Types:
       - "PRIVATE"
   Policy: !Sub
     - |-
       {
         "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [
           {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": "*",
             "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
             "Resource": [
               "execute-api:/*"
             ]
           },
           {
             "Effect": "Deny",
             "Principal": "*",
             "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
             "Resource": [
               "execute-api:/*"
             ],
             "Condition": {
               "StringNotEquals": {
                 "aws:SourceVpc": "${myappid}"    --> i need this as list when run in uat
               }
             }
           }
         ]
       }
    - { myappid: !If [islowenv, !FindInMap [ "mVpcId", "menv",  !Ref "Env" ], !Split [ ",", !FindInMap [ "mVpcId", "menv",  !Ref "Env"] ]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have condition now and your vpc list is hardcoded, you can use the following combination of `Select` and `Sub` to produce valid policy:

```
Mappings:
  mVpcId:
   menv:
    perf: "vpc-1234"
    uat: "vpc-7830jkd,vpc-a1236"

Conditions:
 islowenv: !Equals [ !Ref Env, "perf" ]

Parameters:
   Env:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [perf,uat]

Resources:

 apigateway:
   Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
   Properties:
    Name: mygateway
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Types:
        - "PRIVATE"
    Policy: !Sub
        - |-
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": [
                "execute-api:/*"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": [
                "execute-api:/*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": ${myappid}
                }
               }
            }
            ]
          }
        - myappid:
           !If
             - islowenv
             - !Sub
               - "\"${value}\""
               - value: !FindInMap ["mVpcId", "menv",  !Ref "Env" ]
             - !Sub
               - "[\"${value1}\", \"${value2}\"]"
               - value1: !Select [0, !Split [ ",", !FindInMap [ "mVpcId", "menv",  !Ref "Env"] ]]
                 value2: !Select [1, !Split [ ",", !FindInMap [ "mVpcId", "menv",  !Ref "Env"] ]]
```

But if you need it to work with any vpc list of any length, then you need custom resources or macros.

Comment: Hi..thanks for the time and suggestion. But it didn't worked and gave me below error.  Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null).
tried converting into yaml same error

Comment: @wlg the template works. I verified it. I guess you changed something?

Comment: Template syntax is valid I have verified using designer. But when in deploy in AWS it took  30 minutes , timed out and gave me this error. . Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid

Comment: @Marcin..I didn't change anything in the template. I got same error for uat and perf.

Comment: @wlg My template deploys perfectly fine. Maybe some indentation got mixed up when you copy and pasted it.

Comment: @Marcin..You are the best and made my day. After fixing indentation template deployed successfully. Thank you very Much

Comment: @wlg No problem. Glad it worked out at the end:-)